# Prisma many-to-many relations: create and connect

Tags: typescript, graphql, prisma, prisma-graphql, prisma2

In my Prisma schema, I have a many-to-many relationship between posts and categories. I've added `@map` options to match the Postgres snake_case naming convention:

```
model Post {
  id         Int            @id @default(autoincrement())
  title      String
  body       String?
  categories PostCategory[]

  @@map("post")
}

model Category {
  id    Int            @id @default(autoincrement())
  name  String
  posts PostCategory[]

  @@map("category")
}

model PostCategory {
  categoryId Int      @map("category_id")
  postId     Int      @map("post_id")
  category   Category @relation(fields: [categoryId], references: [id])
  post       Post     @relation(fields: [postId], references: [id])

  @@id([categoryId, postId])
  @@map("post_category")
}
```

I'm trying to create a post with multiple categories at the same time. If a category exists, I'd like to `connect` the category to the post. If the category doesn't exist, I'd like to create it. The creation part is working well, but the connection part is problematic:

```
  await prisma.post.create({
    data: {
      title: 'Hello',
      categories: {
        create: [{ category: { create: { name: 'News' } } }],
        connect: {
          categoryId_postId: { categoryId: 1, postId: ? }, // This doesn't work, even if I had the postId
        },
      },
    },
  });
```

How can I connect an existing category to a new post with the schema that I have?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

What you need here is `connectOrCreate`.

So something like this should work:

```
      await prisma.post.create({
        data: {
          title: 'Hello',
          categories: {
            create: [
              {
                category: {
                  create: {
                    name: 'category-1',
                  },
                },
              },
              { category: { connect: { id: 10 } } },
            ],
          },
        },
      });
```

You can also read more about this in the docs [here](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/relation-queries#create-a-new-profile-record-then-connect-it-to-an-existing-user-record-or-create-a-new-user)

Comment: This exhibits strange behavior. If the `{ categoryId: 1, postId: 1 }` bridge record exists in the `post_category` table, then it replaces the bridge record with `{ categoryId: 1, postId: new_id }`. In other words, it re-assigns another post's category to this new post. I don't want any other post to be impacted when I create a new post. I'd like to create a new category if the category doesn't exist, or add a new bridge record if it does. There's a good example using `create` and `set` on implicit relations here: (url to follow), but it doesn't work b/c I'm using explicit relation.

Comment: Here's the URL that I was referring to in my previous comment: https://www.prisma.io/docs/support/help-articles/working-with-many-to-many-relations#implicit-relations

The example there uses `tags: { set: [{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }], create: { name: 'typescript' } }`, which is what I'd like to do, but can't seem to get it to work with my explicit relationship.

Comment: Based on the docs you linked to, I think I want something like this, but this throws an exception because I can't link from `categoryId_postId` to `category` (sorry about the formatting):        `connectOrCreate: {
              create: {
                category: { create: { name: 'category-1' } },
              },
              where: {
                categoryId_postId: {
                  category: { name: 'category-1' },
                },
              }`

Comment: In that case, this should work: ```await prisma.post.create({
    data: {
      title: 'title',
      categories: { create: { category: { connect: { id: 1 } } } },
    },
  })```

This should connect the post to an existing category and will create the relation in the join table as well.

Answer (score 5):

After hours of trying I finally came up with the following solution for my use case.

```
park[] <-> exercise[]
```

```
// create parks
const parks = await prisma.park.createMany({data: [...]});

// create and connect exercises
const exercises = [...];
await Promise.all(
  exercises.map(async (exercise) => {
    await prisma.exercise.create({
      data: <any>{
        ...exercise,
        parks: {
          connect: parks.map((park) => ({ id: park.id })),
        },
      },
    });
  }),
);
```

Comment: Nice one! This is what I needed, although I opted for a little different expression:
connect: parks.map(({ id }) => ({ id })),

Answer (score 4):

This problem drove me up the wall so I'll contribute my solution here incase it helps someone else. First, read this: https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-schema/relations/many-to-many-relations

My schema is similar to the one in question, only difference is I have Files instead of Posts and Tags instead of Categories. To link the created file's tags to existing tags I used this:

```
  await Promise.all(DEFAULT_FILES[2].map(file => prisma.file.create({
    data: {
      ...file,
      user_id: userId,
      parent_id: homeFolder.id,
      tags: {
        create: file.tags?.map(name => ({
          tag: {
            connect: {
              id: tags.find(t => t.name === name)?.id
            }
          }
        }))
      },
    }
  })))
```

Comment: Could you tell me the type of file in your solution? I got it to work, but don't know the type of the input. I thought it's Prisma.FileCreateInput but tags has no map property.

Comment: It's a `seed.ts` that I execute with `"seed": "ts-node ./prisma/seed.ts"`

Answer (score 1):

```
await prisma.postCategory.create({
  data: {
    category: {
      connectOrCreate: {
        id: categoryId
      }
    },
    posts: {
      create: [
        {
          title: 'g3xxxxxxx',
          body: 'body g3xxxxx'
        }
      ],
    },
  },
})
```

You should connect to the existing record and then create the record that you want to be related with the first one.

https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/relation-queries (Connect an existing record)

Answer (score 0):

Explicit many-to-many create/update existing tags [read more here](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-schema/relations/many-to-many-relations#explicit-many-to-many-relations)

```js
let args =[1,2,3,4]
tags: {
      create: args.tags?.map(tagId=>({
          tag:{
              connect:{
                  id:tagId
              }
          }
      }))
    },
 }
```